# JS - Parsing error for async function

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, async-await, eslint

I created a node.js web application. Currently I'm using MSSQL for the DB. I created functions (sql.js) , to perform the corresponding SQL functions. I also created a async function handlers (controllers.js) so i can use async and await keywords in my router (express). The router calls them with the await keyword. I don't get any errors calling these functions, in fact everything returns data and acts normally, but in my text editor (VSCode), i get the following error

```
[eslint] Parsing error: Unexpected token =>
```

Under further investigation, noticed that in my console I get an un-handled promise error. Which makes me think i defined my controllers incorrectly

```
internal/process/warning.js:18 (node:16328) Warning: a promise was created in a handler at D:\Programs\ColdFusion2016\cfusion\wwwroot\vue_starter\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:335:12 but was not returned from it, see http:// goo.gl/ rRqMUw
    at Function.Promise.attempt.Promise.try (D:\Programs\ColdFusion2016\cfusion\wwwroot\vue_starter\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\method.js:29:9)
```

. Does anyone see something wrong with the controllers?

router.js

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const {
    asyncGet,
    asyncPost
} = require('../services/controllers')(router);
const sql = require('../services/sql');
const request = require('../services/request');

/// Get Users
asyncGet('/controller/getUsers', async(req, res, next) => {
    console.log('get: /controller/getUsers'); 
    const users = await sql.getUsers(); 
    res.status(200).json(users);   
});
/// Get Products
asyncGet('/controller/getProducts', async(req, res, next) => {
    console.log('get: /controller/getProducts'); 
    const products = await sql.getProducts(); 
    res.status(200).json(products);
});

module.exports = router;
```

controllers.js

```
module.exports = (router) => {
    const asyncGet = (route, handler) => {
        return router.get(route, (req, res, next) => {
            handler(req, res, next)
            .catch(error => {
                next(error);
            });
        });
    };
    const asyncPost = (route, handler) => {
        return router.post(route, (req, res, next) => {
            handler(req, res, next)
            .catch(error => {
                next(error);
            });
        });
    };
    return { asyncGet, asyncPost };
};
```

[image]

Comment: `ReferenceError: error is not defined` - but it is defined in the code you've posted. Your real code may differ, or the error refers to another piece of code that wasn't covered in the question. Consider providing https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve that can replicate the problem - a repo, etc. Regarding ESLint error, see the answer.

Comment: @estus, I apologize, i posted the wrong message.I have updated my question with the error my server logs out in the console. The previous message, was from another stack post. I was writing this question out before posting. All the code now matches up 1 to 1.

Comment: The error suggests that Bluebird promise (e.g. Sequelize uses it internally, is it the one you're using?) wasn't chained. But all promises that exist in this snippet (getProducts and getUsers) were implicitly chained with `await`. You can try to comment `await sql.getUsers()`, etc to check if it's the issue, but I'd expect this error to happen elsewhere. It's not evident that the error takes place in the code you've posted.

Comment: @estus, yeah you could be right, i was just thinking that maybe the eslint was picking up the un-handled promise.

Comment: No, seem to be unrelated problems. But the warning indicates a real mistake. You have a promise somewhere which you forgot to chain.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order for ESLint to support `async..await`, its support [should be enabled](https://github.com/eslint/eslint/issues/1657#issuecomment-252500711) in ESLint configuration:

```
{
    "parserOptions": {
        "ecmaVersion": 2017
    }
}
```

Comment: @lolbas The linter likely bailed out after syntax error. It clearly doesn't understand async arrow.

Comment: @estus, you were correct about the eslint, it had nothing to do with the un-handled promise.

Comment: I hope it helped in part then.

Comment: @estus, yeah. Another file was throwing that error, so I'm not sure if i should edit the question and then accept your answer, or if i should just accept it.

Comment: Considering that the title already says about that, editing it would help other users that have same problem.